# Failure delivering result ResultInfo in Action Bar Sherlock, Facebook

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the Action bar sherlock library in my application and I currently have one two tabs as fragments:

Tab A : Users views information in a list
Tab B : Users can log into facebook

I need the onActivityResult() to handle Facebook sessions in Tab B so I have this code in my Main Activity :

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

However, this creates this error log when i press the Back Button in Tab A:

```
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.chartviewer/com.example.chartviewer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at com.example.chartviewer.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:91)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
04-02 19:46:07.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     ... 11 more
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: What's line 91 of `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @t0mm13b Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: Is `Session` null? Is `this` (the first parameter to `onActivityResult` null?) log it to see and determine which of them is null?

Comment: @t0mm13b thanks i eventually found my error.

Comment: can you please share your code, how you solve this error @AndroidEnthusiast